# Вопрос к работе DTO

Tags: c#, reactjs, visual-studio

*Другое оглавление: Смогу ли я получить доступ к скрытым полям в классе ToDoItems(скрыты они потому что есть такой же класс ToDoItemsDTO) в React App используя API?*

Я пытаюсь создать `WebAPI` для `ReactApp`, что бы связать `DB` и Front-end используя `MVC`, создаю я Back-end по [руководству Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio), там почти в самом конце есть объяснение, как использовать `Data Transfer Object(DTO)`, что бы скрыть некоторые поля и мы не имели к ним доступа `POST` или `Get`, . И вот мой вопрос: смогу ли я в дальнейшем при подключении этого `API` к `ReactApp` использовать те самые скрытые поля, что бы присваивать им значения и выводить на экран уже с помощью `React`, например `<table>` с ними?

вот пример:
у меня в папке `Models` есть класс `UserItem` в которому описаны все поля из таблицы DB : **Id, Name, Email, Password** и `UserItemDTO` где описаны только **Id, Name**, после я создал `UserController` сделал там `CRUD` с использованием `DTO` и подключил это всё к ReactApp. Смогу ли я в `ReactApp` изменять или получать те самые Password и Email поля, которые скрыты?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что эти поля не скрыты. Их просто нет! Как можно скрыть то, чего нет?
Если Вам нужны какие-то поля в react-е, так делайте dto с этими полями.

Comment: Кажется я совершення не правильно понял смысл DTO, спасибо. Хотя теперь понимая это я задаю себе впорос зачем я вообще создал эту тему, и вы правы, нельзя скрыть то, чего не существует

Comment: Есть какой то смысл создавать в DTO всё кроме Id, мне не нужно, что бы могли его менять и это отличный способ этого избежать?

Comment: Или и просто так нельзя сменить Id ?

Comment: DTO сао по себе ничего не изменяет. Изменяет метод, который Вы напишите сами. Будет ли он учитывать то или иное поле - зависит от Вас. Тогда особого смысла нет.
Если используете сторонние фреймвёрки/библиотеки, и не знаете точно как они поступают с полями, то лишние наверное стоит убрать.

Comment: id не принято менять. И может быть даже запрещено.

Comment: Окей, спасибо, понятно что id менять не принято да и не нужно( в большинстве своём).